# Woocommerce multiples product checkout with categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

First: sorry for my english.

I have two categories on my woocomerce store, ona called: "Vasos" and another one called: "Cervezas"

I want the users buy on multiples of 6 only, but if they add to cart products of both categories(vasos and cervezas) then they have to add 6 products of each category to proceed to pay.

Hoy can i do that?

Here is the code im using, im not sure what im doing wrong.

Thanks for the help!

```
$multiples = 6;
$total_products = 0;
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $total_products += $values['quantity'];

    $_product = $values['data'];
    $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );
    $cat_ids = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $cat_ids[] = $term->term_id;
    }
}

if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 && in_array(479, (array)$cat_ids)  ) {
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('Debes seleccionar cervezas en múltiplos de %s para realizar la compra. Por ejemplo: 6, 12, 18, 24...', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}

if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 && in_array(171, (array)$cat_ids)  ) {
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('Debes seleccionar vasos en múltiplos de %s para realizar la compra. Por ejemplo: 6, 12, 18, 24...', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: it is more traditional to enter the 6 pack as a product itself...